# How to save edits in datatable to workspace

Tags: r, dt

Consider this datatable.

```
library(DT)
data <- mtcars
datatable(data, editable = TRUE)
```

If i run the code, the datatable opens in the viewer pane and i made a lot of edits. How can i save the results now to the workspace/file?
The only option i see in the Viewer pane is to Export as html file. If i run `data` in the console i get the old input before the edits. 
Also  `data2 <- datatable(data, editable = TRUE)` does not work for me.

Using a shiny app could work but seems a bit like an overkill,...

Update:

It was asked in 04.2018 on rstudio.com: https://community.rstudio.com/t/is-it-possible-to-save-edits-made-in-a-dt-table/7000.
No solution so far,...

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `save(data2, "data2.RData")`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I havent declared data2 yet. I only used the Code at the top,...and the data variable in the enviroment stayed unchanged,...

Comment: In that case, first do something like `data2 <- data` and make whatever edit you want it in `data2`. That way you preserve the original data and you will have the edited date in `data2`

Comment: If it is a lot of work, and you don't want to lose it, probably export to html is your best bet. You can copy and paste it into a spreadsheet then save as a .csv to read in to R later.

Comment: @AaronHayman: Thanks thats a valid Workaround, i would upvote that. @ MaMu Does that really work for you? I tested and for me it doesnt. @ all using a shiny app it could work, but it seems a bit like an Overkill. Plus, the Information is stored somewhere, so it might be accessible,...Maybe ist worth an issue,...

Comment: Have you tried to export to CSV with the Buttons extension ?

Comment: no, i havent. great Extension. If you add it as an answer, i would accept it!